# Can I derive ARRAY_CONTAINS from query method name in Spring Data Couchbase Repository?

Tags: java, sql++, spring-data-couchbase

I have a Couchbase-Document "Group" with a list of group-members-names. I want to query for all groups of one person. I managed to do it with [N1QL ARRAY_CONTAINS](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/arrayfun.html#fn-array-contains) - see in code example - but i hoped that i could generate the query from the method name as it is usual in Spring Data.

Any help is appreciated :)

#### I tried

`public List<MyGroup> findAllByMembers(String member);` and `public List<MyGroup> findByMembers(String member);` but they just return an empty list - i guess they try to match the whole "members" value and don't recognize it as a list -, no errors.

#### Code

My Document with a List field

```java
@Data
@Document
public class MyGroup {
    private String name;
    private List<String> members = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

My Repository

```java
@RepositoryDefinition(domainClass = MyGroup.class, idClass = String.class)
public interface MyGroupRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<MyGroup, String> {

    //@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(members,$1) AND #{#n1ql.filter}")
    public List<MyGroup> findAllByMembers(String member);
}
```

#### Expected

Given a "group1" with "member1" in members.
repository.findAllByMembers("member1"); should return ["group1"].

Answer (score 2):

Couchbase is limited by the Spring Data specification. Unfortunately, we can't simply add new behaviors to it (if you switch to a relational database, it has to work with no breaking points). So, whenever you need to query something that has a N1QL specific function/keyword, you have to write a query via @Query

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Couchbase is limited by the Spring Data specification." As i understand Spring-Data-Couchbase is just a facade to N1QL and is limited by Couchbase's N1QL. Couchbase N1QL has the function so Spring Data could use it, not only via @Query.

Comment: Spring Data was created by Pivotal https://spring.io/projects/spring-data and it is supported by most relational databases. Couchbases added support for it also, but anything that cannot be done in a relational database (like array search in your case) cannot be expressed via method name conventions.